# Receiver 'SMClient' for class message is a forward declaration

Tags: ios, objective-c, forward-declaration, appdelegate

I'm trying to add [StackMob](http://stackmob.com) to my project. It says to create an `SMClient` instance after having dragged the SDK to the project, checking 'create groups for..' and adding to target. I followed these [steps](https://developer.stackmob.com/start#step2).

However, when I'm creating my `SMClient` and `SMCoreDataStore` instances, it gives me an error of `Receiver 'SMClient' for class message is a forward declaration` and the same for `SMCoreDataStore`. Here's my code:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@class SMClient;
@class SMCoreDataStore;

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) SMCoreDataStore *coreDataStore;
@property (strong, nonatomic) SMClient *client;

@end
```

And part of my `.m`:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "StackMob.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.client = [[SMClient alloc] initWithAPIVersion:@"0" publicKey:@"YOUR_PUBLIC_KEY"];
    self.coreDataStore = [self.client coreDataStoreWithManagedObjectModel:self.managedObjectModel];

    return YES;
}
```

I already cleaned the project, imported the relevant header files, but it still gives that error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This might be happening because you forgot to import the classes.
Add it on your .m:

```
#import "SMClient.h"
#import "SMCoreDataStore.h"
```

Comment: That fixes it! But that's strange, because `StackMob.h` imports those two classes, although if I only import that header file, it gives me that error.